# Todonotes custom counter not referencing in align environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align, counters, todonotes

I have set up `todonotes` with a counter and would like to reference the tasks I create.

In the align environment, I am unable to place the task in the margin so it is inline in a `\text{}` command.

Ideally I would like to have all tasks in the margin but I am okay if for equations they are inline.

The main problem I am having is that I cannot reference a task that is in an equation as demonstrated in the MWE. The reference points to the equation (1) and not task T2.

How do I fix this?

Thank you for the help

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{suffix}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcounter{task}
\renewcommand{\thetask}{T\arabic{task}}

\newcommand{\task}[2][]{%
    \refstepcounter{task}%
    \todo[#1]{{\bf \thetask} #2}%
}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\task*[2][]{%
    \refstepcounter{task}%
    \quad%
    \text{%
        \todo[inline, inlinewidth=4.5cm, #1]{{\bf \thetask} #2}%
    }
}


\begin{document}

This is my\task{Adjust formatting.}\label{task formatting} document.

\begin{align}
    y   & =     5x + 2 \task*{Decided which one}\label{task choose}  \\
        & =     2 + 5x
\end{align}

The tasks were formatting~\ref{task formatting} and choosing the equation~\ref{task choose}.

\end{document}
```

Which gives
[image]